# How to write a high performance sql query app in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core, ado.net

I create a new empty asp.net core project and type some code like below.
but QPS just around 600.(hello world test php 6000,asp.net core 10000,php with PDO do the same work around 1000)

Ubuntu 20.04 ab -c 1000 -n 50000  http://localhost:4246/

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
        {
            var list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            MySqlConnection myConnnect;
            MySqlCommand sqlCmd;
            myConnnect = new MySqlConnection(constructorString);
            sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.Connection = myConnnect;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "select * from location where parent_id=0";
            await myConnnect.OpenAsync();
            
            using (var reader = await sqlCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    data["id"] = reader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                    data["spell_first"] = reader.GetString(2);
                    data["spell_full"] = reader.GetString(3);
                    data["name"] = reader.GetString(4);
                    list.Add(data);
                }
            }


            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
```

Comment: Make sure hardware and network performance is good. These factor also play major role

Answer (score 0):

Since your focus is on queries per second by a single thread, rather than optimizing for lots of threads running queries, you might try having the reader read in a non async way.  That will avoid context switching for your thread while reading in the recs.

Also, and this could be the bigger issue, using a dictionary to hold the fields for a record is going to involve a lot more memory management then using a dedicated class for them, so I'd recommend making that change as well.  The final code might look like:

[note I didn't run this code since I don't have your database ;-) so the code could have syntax errors]

```
public class Rec{
    public int Id;
    public string SpellFirst;
    public string SpellFull;
    public string Name;
}
```

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
        {
            var list = new List<Rec>();
            MySqlConnection myConnnect;
            MySqlCommand sqlCmd;
            myConnnect = new MySqlConnection(constructorString);
            sqlCmd = new MySqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.Connection = myConnnect;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "select * from location where parent_id=0";
            await myConnnect.OpenAsync();
            
            using (var reader = await sqlCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var rec = new Rec();
                    rec.Id = reader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                    rec.SpellFirst = reader.GetString(2);
                    rec.SpellFull = reader.GetString(3);
                    rec.Name = reader.GetString(4);
                    list.Add(rec);
                }
            }


            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
```

Give that a whirl and see what the numbers are.